# Why is it not return any sequence within the string?

Tags: python

So for this code I want to input any string and I want it to return true if there's a sequence of 3 same consecutive characters in n.

This code works however, it only counts the first three consecutive numbers in n, but I want it to count any sequence in n.

```py
def consec(n):
  for i in range(len(n)):
      if n[i] == n[i+1] == n[i+2]: 
          return True
      else:
          return False
```

eg: if consec("AAABC")

it prints true

but if consec("ABCCC")

it prints false even though there are 3 consecutive characters, they just happen to be later in the string.

What should I change about this code ?

Thanks,

Comment: You are immediately returning `False` if the first 3 characters aren't the same.  You should only return `False` after the loop finishes (eg, if it didn't return `True` during the loop).  Also, you should run the loop through `range(len(n)-2)`, otherwise you will index off the end of the string.

Comment: Why range(len(n)-2) ?

Comment: Because you are checking `n[i+2]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract 3 or more consecutive characters:

```
import re

def check_string(text):
    if re.findall(r'(\w)\1\1+', text):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code. Currently it only checks the first 3 letters because of the range being between 0 and 1. If you do some print debugging with print(n[i], n[i + 1], n[i + 2]) you will see that consec("ABCCC") will only print A B C.

The second problem is that if you fix the above mentioned problem it will still only check the first 3 letters. This is because if the "if n[i]....." isn't True, it will not go to another iteration of the for loop. Instead it will return False. This you can fix by making the function only return False if it doesnt find 3 consecutive letters in any iteration.

Im assuming this is homework so the I'm not providing working code, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

your `for` loop only iterates one time that's why you are getting incorrect responses? Try like this:

```
def consec(n):
    result = False
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if result:
            return result
        if n[i] == n[i + 1] == n[i + 2]:
            result = True
        else:
            result = False
    return result
```

By this the loop will only stop if there are consecutive 3 characters or all characters are already iterated.

Answer (score 0):

Move `return False` to outside of the loop and check reversely from the last index to avoid index error:

```
def consec(n):
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if n[i] == n[i-1] == n[i-2]:
            return True
    return False
```

Or add `-2` in `range(len(n)`:

```
def consec(n):
    for i in range(len(n)-2):
        if n[i] == n[i+1] == n[i+2]:
            return True
    return False
```

You can also use `any()`:

```
def consec(n):
    return any(n[i] == n[i-1] == n[i-2] for i in range(len(n)))
```

Or

```
def consec(n):
    return any(n[i] == n[i+1] == n[i+2] for i in range(len(n)-2))
```